# My JavaScript is not working! Help :(

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, for-loop

I'm new here. I have spent the entire day trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. Yes, it might be a simple questions for you, since I just started JavaSript about a month ago. Anyways, your help in identifying the error in my code is greatly appreciated!

==========================================================================

The Question:

Code a function called extremeValue. It takes 2 parameters. The first is an array of integers (you do not need to validate this). The second parameter is either the String “Minimum” or “Maximum”. The function returns the minimum or maximum element value in the array depending on the second parameter’s value.

Do not use Math.min or Math.max. The standard algorithm for finding a minimum value in an array is to assume the first element (at index 0) is the current minimum. Then process the array repetitively from its second element to its last. On each iteration compare the current element being processed with the current minimum. If it’s less than the minimum set it as the current minimum. In this way at the end of processing the current minimum holds the minimum element value in the array. A similar process will work for finding the maximum. Test your code. (1 mark)

This function does two different jobs depending on its second parameter. What are the pros and cons of this approach to coding functions?

My Answer (which doesn't work):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Eng1003 Workshop Code Week 04</title>
<style>
    #outputArea{
        padding: .25em;
        border: solid black 2px;
        margin: 3em;

        height: 20em;
        width: 20em;

        overflow-y: scroll;

        font-family: arial "sans serif";
        font-size: 1em;
        color: rgb(50, 50, 250);

        background-color: rgb(225,225,225) ;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<!--    -->     
    <div id="outputArea"></div>

    <script>

        function maximum(setOfValues){
            var retVal = "" ; 
            var length = setOfValues.length ;
            var max = 0  ;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
                if (setOfValues[i] > max){
                    max = setOfValues[i] ;
                }
            }
            retVal = max ;
            return retVal ;
        }

        function minimum(setOfValues){
            var retVal = "";
            var length = setOfValues.length ;
            var min = 0  ;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
                if (setOfValues[i] < min){
                    min = setOfValues[i] ;
                } 
            }
            retVal = min;
            return retVal ;
        }

        function extremeValue(setOfValues, command){
            var outString = "" ;    
            var retVal = "" ;    
            if (command = "Maximum"){ 
                outString = "The maximum value is " + maximum(setOfValues) + "."  ;
            } else if (command = "Minimum"){
                outString = "The minimum value is " + minimum(setOfValues) + "." ;
            } else {
                outString = "Sorry, but your command is unclear. Please ensure that your input is either 'Maximum' or 'Minimum'." ;
            }
            retVal = outString ; 
            return retVal ;
        }

        var target = document.getElementById("outputArea") ;
        var inputCommand = prompt("What is your command?") ;
        var inputValues = [10,30,500, 1000] ;
        var finalAnswer = "" ;

        finalAnswer = extremeValue(inputValues, inputCommand) ;
        target.innerHTML = finalAnswer ;

      </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you're checking your prompted value:

```
if (command = "Minimum")
if (command = "Maximum")
```

Here you're *assigning* strings to `command`. The code should be (assuming we're using [`strict equality`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)):

```
if (command === "Minimum")
if (command === "Maximum")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j70wwr4o/5/)

Answer (score 0):

In you HTML page, call the Result function as below:

```
<script>
    Result.init();
</script>

var Result = function () {
    var maximum = function (array) {
        var val = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > val) {
                val = array[i];
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
    var minimum = function (array) {
        var val = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            val = array[i];
            if (array[i] < val) {
                val = array[i];
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
    var start = function () {
        var inputValues = [10, 30, 500, 1000];
        var min = minimum(inputValues);
        var max = maximum(inputValues);
    }
    return {
        init: function () {
            start();
        }
    };
}();
```